# Reducing this lambda expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

I’m trying to practice beta reduction but I’m stuck on how to reduce this problem:

```
(λx((λy.x)(λx.x))x)y
```

The outermost `λx` will obviously be substituted with `y`, but should I still proceed with reducing `((λy.x)(λx.x))`? What am I missing here?

Comment: I think SO is the wrong place for this question!

Comment: @Passe Why do you think so?

Comment: I think you're missing a `.` after `λx`. Also, `λx` will disappear after beta reduction. Substitution happens to the `x`s in the body of the lambda.

Comment: @melpomene Can you elaborate on your comment and post an answer instead?

Comment: @LeeMerlas For a real answer I'd have to look up lambda calculus and the details of beta reduction (and alpha renaming because there's an inner `y` and an outer `y`, so you need to rename one of them). What's unclear about beta reduction?

Comment: @melpomene I’m just confused if I need to reduce ((λy.x)(λx.x)

Comment: @LeeMerlas I guess that depends on whether you allow reduction "under lambda". I'm not sure what's standard in LC; programming languages generally don't do this.

Comment: @LeeMerlas That said, in this case it doesn't matter in which order you reduce things. All reduction orders terminate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’m trying to practice beta reduction but I’m stuck on how to reduce this problem:
>
> ```
> (λx((λy.x)(λx.x))x)y
> ```

To perform the first β-reduction you have to look at the variables `x` bound by the outer `λx`, which are,

```
(λx((λy.x)(λx.x))x)y
        ^        ^
```

Note that in the inner `λx.x` shadows the outer lambda since it uses the same variable name. So the bound `x` here is bound to this inner lambda, not the outer one.

Another problem is that if you substitute `y` for `x` in `λy.x` then `y` is captured by the outer lambda. That cannot happen, so you need to perform an α-conversion (renaming) on `λy.x`to avoid the capture.

So first the α-conversion, the the β-reduction

```
  (λx((λy.x)(λx.x))x)y
→ (λx((λz.x)(λx.x))x)y
→    ((λz.y)(λx.x))y
```

If you want to continue then `λz.y` returns `y` for any input,

```
  ((λz.y)(λx.x))y
→ yy
```

---

Note the λ-calculus doesn't set a reduction strategy, it only establishes an equivalence relation between terms. So you can pick another reduction order. For instance you could β-reduce the inner β-redex `(λy.x)(λx.x)` first.

```
  (λx((λy.x)(λx.x))x)y
→ (λx(xx)y
→ yy
```

This would have avoided the α-conversion.